# Start a local program from Chrome/Chromium browser

Tags: google-chrome, local, execution

What are the options for executing a local client-side program directly from Chrome/Chromium?

Here's the criteria:

- ease of installation
- cross-platform support
- control over security (no other than the specified program can be
  executed)

Currently, I can think of three options

1. write a Chrome plugin
2. clients run a local web server
3. a Java Applet

Are there any other options? The client side runs Javascript and is accessing a RESTful API to receive the data. Or maybe a way to directly execute a local program with the user's consent from Chrome?

Comment: Does this local client-side program already exist, or is it downloaded from your server?

Comment: It does not exist yet and needs to be downloaded.

Comment: You could just do what other sites do, which is to provide instructions on what to do after downloading the program. You will also need to point users to the correct version for their OS (either manually or based on browser headers)

Other than that, I would recommend writing it as a web app (HTML5, JS, and local storage)

Comment: Unfortunately, some parts of the app require the native code to run on the client side. There is no work-around for this.